# How to keep styles consistent in CSS across sites?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am building a pluggable chatbot widget using react. I am aiming for a chatbot widget which you can use on any site sort of like [rasa-webchat](https://github.com/botfront/rasa-webchat).

When I used it on some of the sites I found its styles being overridden by the base site on which the widget was added. On debugging I found out that the base site is using styles with `!important` in their CSS sort of like

```css
a {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

which really screwed up my widget styling, so no matter how specific styles I used in my widget CSS it will be overwritten by the base site styles having `!important`.
I found 'css-modules','react-jss'  libraries to scope css but none was able to override !important,  the only way I found is to add `!important` to all the styles in my CSS but that is considered a bad approach and since I am using material-ui to build my chatbot I believe it will be hard to add `!important` to each and every style in the library itself.

Is there any way with which I can ensure that my widget styling will look same irrespective of base site CSS ?

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference would be to use Styled Components.

With Styled Components you can override styles with higher specificity. The example in the documentation, found [here](https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#how-can-i-override-styles-with-higher-specificity), covers exactly what you are asking.

There are also a number of other benefits with using Styled components, ranging from readability to performance gains.

[Styled Components Docs](https://styled-components.com/docs)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response but my issue is that the parent site is using `!important` in its style as i mentioned in my example above which i cannot change. What styled component does is as mentioned in your link is it increases the cssspecificity of the targeted element but still `!important` of the pparent site  has final say . I can add !important in my styles which will override the base site !important but i have to add it to each and every CSS line of my stylesheet to ensure that in future no other styles get overridden

Comment: Since I am using external library for styling (material-ui) , i have to repeat the same process of adding `!important` to each and everyline there , which is not scalabe. Kindly revert if i am unclear somewehere

Comment: Interesting, so important in your code will override the parent site site's "final say" but Styled components specificity wont? I'll have a play around and see if I can replicate what you say.

Comment: Thanks for you prompt response, yeah on parent site they have '!important' in their styles which has most CSS specificity in the entire page and to counter it i have to add !important in my styles with more specificity , pardon if i sound repetitive, kindly let me know if you can't replicate it , i will link a sandbox or codepen for it

Comment: here is a code pen of the issue which i am facing, i have also tried to include what styled components do [click here](https://codepen.io/isam9/pen/poJzYJp?editors=1100)

Comment: "With Styled Components you can override styles with higher specificity. The example in the documentation, found here, covers exactly what you are asking." — I've looked at that and can only call it "an unreliable hack". Shoving the same class name in multiple times does bump up the specificity, but not against `!important`, rules with ID selectors, rules which target properties you haven't set explicitly, rules which target elements you haven't set explicitly, and so on.